# Firestore query with 'array-contains-any' operator not returning expected data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Update -
@Frank van Puffelen
Here are the screenshots on the data I am expecting from firestore from my webpage -

**Screenshot 1**

This is the data I am expecting from
`.where('qS', 'array-contains-any', [1,2])`
[image]

**ScreenShot 2**
This is the data I am expecting from
`.where('qS', 'array-contains-any', [2])`
[image]

If I was not clear before -
The operand value getFV changes based on button clicks from three buttons, setting return to `[1,2]`, `[1]`, or `[2]`. I created a method to manage this dynamic change, avoiding the need for multiple conditional statements for each button click scenario.
FV from console -
[image: fv from console]

Even though the getFV method returns the exact array needed for the operand in this where clause .where('qS', 'array-contains-any', fV) (Attached sccreenshot tagged - FV from console), it consistently retrieves data from ***Screenshot 1***, regardless of the buttons clicked.

However, when I manually input the same array that was returned from the ***Screenshot 2*** directly into the code, like this .where('qS', 'array-contains-any', [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmaxJ.png)), I get the desired data.
[image: fv from console single]

I am using Firestore to fetch data based on a filter that utilizes the 'array-contains-any' operator.
Here is the code I am using to fetch the data -

```
const fV = this.getFV(this.selectedButton);
return qnaCollectionRef
.where('qS', 'array-contains-any' , fV)
.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
```

here is the code for getFv

```
getFV(qF: QF): number[] {
    debugger;
    switch (qF) {
      case QF.All:
        return [1,2];
      case QF.O:
        return [1];
      case QF.A:
        return [2];
      default:
        throw new Error('Unsupported filter option');
    }
  }
```

Assume that my firestore db contains data like

```
for QF.All - [abc, dce, efg, hij]
for QF.O - [abc, dce]
for QF.A - [efg, hij]
```

Now I have a button which changes this fV to [1,2], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmaxJ.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Zo3.png) which gets called in below query

```
.where('qS', 'array-contains-any' , fV)
```

The issue I'm facing is that regardless of the filter values I pass in fVs, the query always returns data from the fv [1,2]. However, when I modify the query and hardcode the operand to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmaxJ.png) or [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Zo3.png), it correctly returns the desired data from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmaxJ.png) or [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Zo3.png).

```
.where('qS', 'array-contains-any', [2])
```

Comment: Can you please review your question: `qs`==`questionState`? `fV`==`filterValues`? Also you make it confusing by using `1` and `2` as variables, can you simply put the code you run?

Comment: Can you also log the value of `fv` before running the query

Comment: Can edit your question to show a screenshot from the Firestore console of a document that you expect to get back?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @l1b3rty sorry About that. I have made the changes in the question.
Basically I have a button which gets called in the switch case to return an array of numbers be it single or multiple indexes. which will get in fV of where clause.
And I logged the statement  it is consistently giving the desired array I want based on the button click. but doesn't return the desired data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the question with screenshots. I have also added clarification after If I was not clear  - before 
in case my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the screenshots frank asked for let me know if you neeed anything else

Comment: When I use a hard-coded array, it works fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-compat-pagination?file=index.js. Can you make the **minimal change** to that repro so that it breaks?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the code in stackblitz. I have called the variable as const first for reference and hard coding the value of selectedQf for on load.

Comment: Oops, it looks like I shared the wrong link yesterday. This is the stackblitz instance where I tried to reproduce your problems: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-compat-array-contains-any?file=index.js

You will have to fork that to modify it, so once you reproduce the issue, share **your** URL so we can have a look.